# How to detect HDD in "This PC" of my Acer notebook/tablet hybrid?

Tags: windows-10, acer-aspire

Edit: I already edited this question, fixed my former problems by using Drivers Pack Solution to automatically detect my hardware and install corresponding drivers.

Info: I reformatted an ACER Aspire Switch 10 SW3-016 using a Win10 ISO. Installed drivers using the Pack Solution. However, before reformatting, I did a format on the 500 GB HDD (not a quick format), it took some time and midway through the format, I undocked the tablet part only to find out that it stopped the format. I docked it again and then did a quick format on the hdd.

I then installed a clean copy of win10. Now I can't see the hdd in my "This PC" window. It still shows in diskpart and diskmanagement, in Ease US partition and partition wizard tool apps but I can't use it, I can't create a partition on it, it always remain as an Unallocated logical drive. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: I'm sorry to say, there is something seriously wrong that we are missing. You didn't mention why you reloaded your computer. There's no chance a legitimate, unmodified copy of Windows 10 freshly installed on your computer would not recognize basic keyboard and mouse controls. Where did you get the Windows 10 installation media? Sounds like there is hardware failure on your system. Has liquid or something been spilled on it?

Comment: I see this is a tablet. Have you tried an external USB mouse plugged directly in to the tablet with and without the keyboard dock plugged in? Being it is a tablet, it is possible being that it is USB 3.0 that some driver is missing. Typically systems have standard USB ports also. But, sometimes USB 3.0 drivers are needed. I'd still be surprised if Windows 10 couldn't handle that out of the box though. It also should recognize the touch screen out of the box though I would think.

Comment: I believe I'm using an unmodified ISO when I installed win10, I'd done it with other pc's before and all worked but for this one which is a hybrid, I don't know why it doesn't. Again, after restarting the device, those 3 inputs work for a while but then freeze again after some minutes. I can't update device drivers because it doesn't even detect a wireless lan device. I downloaded available drivers from acer website but after installing wifi driver, it still does not register in device manager.

Comment: anyway, I reloaded it since the previous installation has so many problems. Settings app does not open (opens for a second and then closes immediately), shortcut virus, does not recognize wireless networks, etc.

Comment: I would try one more time with the latest version of Windows 10 downloaded here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10  You can make a bootable USB drive to try with again.

Comment: i'm afraid I don't have enough connection speed to download another win10 iso right now :)
anyway, does a win10 iso contain a generic driver for most wireless devices? touchpad? keyboard? touchscreen?

Comment: Yes, basic devices like these are usually supported out of the box. That is why I'm saying it is highly unlikely Windows 10 wouldn't work right out of the box with basic items like mouse and keyboard. Even Windows XP could do that. There has to be something else going on. The only thing I can think of is that because it is a tablet with USB 3.0 that there is some intermediate hardware that is not being recognized which supports all the USB functionality. But, this makes it extremely hard for you to install anything. I have yet to see this scenario with Windows 10.

Comment: I also can't explain why it would work for a few minutes, then quit. All I can figure is that Windows is automatically installing some additional drivers it downloads from the internet and is actually breaking something. So, you might try disabling any internet connection and then working with it for a while to see if the devices keep working. This will lead you in a better direction possibly.

Comment: Windows can't do that since the device does not even connect to the internet, I'm using a different laptop right now.
I looked for the wireless device in device manager but nothing's there. I installed Realtek driver from Acer for the device and installed it, but it did not even register in device manager because the section for network devices is missing.